# Visual Basic 2008 Sort Two Dependent Arraylists with Different Values

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm new to VB.Net and have homework problem to which I cannot find a good answer to. I have a program that takes two 1D arrays from two different files and sorts them. I built my arrays with ArrayList (I can't get my textfiles to load into regular arrays for some reason).

Say for instance I have the following two string ArrayLists:
Figurines contains Dog, Cat, Bird, Fish
Prices contains 2000, 2500, 1500, 1000

I need to perform four kinds of sorts: Ascending and Descending on Figurines and Ascending and Descending on Prices. Here's the problem. A normal display should look like this:

```
Figurines         Prices
     Dog           2000
     Cat           2500
     Bird          1500
     Fish          1000
```

If I do an ascending sort on the Figurines ArrayList (Figurines.Sort), the Prices ArrayList has to match the Figurines.

```
Figurines         Prices
     Bird          1500     
     Cat           2500
     Dog           2000
     Fish          1000
```

Sorting on one array is no problem, but getting the dependent array to sort with it has stumped me and I haven't been able to find any resources for something like this.

The files are similar in structure (one alphabet, one numerical) but longer. These need to be in 1D arrays and I am not allowed to use multi-dimensional arrays. I hope someone can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: To get your files read into arrays, use something like this:  Dim Figurines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("filename")  and do the same thing with the Prices.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Please stop adding the homework tag to questions, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/trogdor-ate-my-homework-tag

Answer (score 0):

Normally I'd suggest putting the values into a 2D array, sorting, then splitting them out into separate arrays again but, being a homework assignment, I wonder if the goal of the project might be for you to implement a sorting algorithm on your own and then sort both arrays as you go. (In other words, this solution may not get you a good grade.)

Answer (score 0):

If you write out the values you have in your example on eight pieces of paper and sort them by hand, moving one piece of paper at a time, does that give you an idea how to do it in code?